# Bash script error "unexpected token" determining php command

Tags: bash

my code is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

function execute_php () {

process=$(ps -A | grep php)
if [-z "$process"]; then echo "no php running" fi

}

(sleep 5 && execute_php)
```

I am trying to determine if the command "php" is being executed, but I get the error "line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `}'"

I am a newbie with bash scripting, and even though I searched for the error, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if [-z "$process"]`

needs to have spaces:

```
if [ -z "$process" ]
```

This is almost certainly duplicated in at least 1000 different questions, but the short of it is that you are trying to invoke a command named `[`, but you are accidentally invoking a command named `[-z` which probably doesn't exist in your PATH.  `[` is not part of the grammar.  It is a command.  This would be more clear if you instead write:

```
if test -z "$process"
```

Also, you're missing a semi-colon (or a newline) before `fi`.

Note further that you can more easily check the status of grep by just checking it directly:

```
execute_php () {
    if ! ps -A | grep -q php; then echo "no php running"; fi
}
```

And further note that this would probably be better if it returned non-zero if the desired process is not running:

```
execute_php() { 
    if ! ps -A | grep -q php; then echo "no php running" >&2; return 1; fi
}
```

But, honestly that's too verbose (and the name of the function seems wrong.  You're not executing anything.)  IMO, you should just write:

```
check_php() {
    ps -A | grep -q php
}
```

and then callers can do `if check_php; then ...`.

Comment: Thanks god people like you exists in this world